# `getline` hangs without closing pipe[1]

Tags: c, linux, pipe, getline

I am writing a program with `fork()` and `pipe()` to make the child process write to the pipe and the parent process read(with `getline()`) from the pipe.  But without closing `pipe[1]` in the parent process, `getline()` hangs forever.  Why does this happen?

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  I read the manual but it does not mention why `getline()` may hang in there.

A simple buggy version of my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
  int fd[2];
  char *s = NULL;
  size_t n = 0;
  int rt;
  pipe(fd);

  pid_t pid = fork();
  if (pid != 0) {
    //close(fd[1]); // without this line, getline() hangs
    dup2(fd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
    close(fd[0]);
    while ((rt = getline(&s, &n, stdin)) != -1) {
      printf("rt: %d\n", rt);
    }
  } else {
    close(fd[0]);
    dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
    close(fd[1]);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
      printf("aaa\n");
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "read" end of the pipe will not see an end-of-file condition until all references to the "write" end of the pipe have been closed. `fork()` increments the references of all open file descriptions. `pipe(fd)` creates the pipe with the two open file descriptions set to blocking mode, so if nothing is writing the "write" end of the pipe, a read operation on the "read" end on the pipe will be blocked indefinitely.